# Whitelist WeTransfer in Spamassassin

Tags: spamassassin, whitelist

trying to whitelist wetransfer emails in spamassassin but somehow doesn't work, conf lines:

```
whitelist_from_rcvd     *@email.wetransfer.com                  wetransfer.com
whitelist_from_rcvd     *=mydomain.com@email.wetransfer.com                  wetransfer.com
```

but any of these above doesn't work. I did a lot of whitelisting but somehow I think is "=" in the sender brakes the chain, dunno how but still cannot find info about it.

EDIT (add):

also when I blacklist addresses and there is "=" in the sender also doesn't blacklist.

Comment: did you restart spamassassin after changing the configuration?

Comment: Yes, I did, usual practice when add/remove from the whitelist, it works for everyone except wetransfer, also when I blacklist addresses and there is "=" in the sender also doesn't blacklist.